# Veracode CWE ID 252: Unchecked Return Value

Tags: ios, objective-c, veracode

How to fix Unchecked Return Value Error according to Veracode's scan report

**Unchecked Return Value Error**:- Line 1: "char *machine = malloc(size);"

```
char *machine = malloc(size);
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

free(machine);
```

Comment: Well when you have no memory this code will fail. Nothing suspicious, just check machine!=NULL after malloc and only then go on. If you choose a specific type of scan, trust the output.

Comment: @OlSen Your suggested solution worked and cleared these type of errors in the veracode scan report. Thanks.